# where and how do I correctly free malloc'd pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I am in a C programming course right now, and am making a shell similar to bash. Right now, I am working on implementing piping. For this reason, I needed to `strndup` the piped command to not modify the original piped command when parsing it. At the end, I tried to `free` the `malloc`'d pointer, but then my program does not work correctly. Can someone please inform me of what I am doing wrong? Below is the code for the while loop for my parser:

```
   while (pipeSeparatedCommand != NULL) {
        char *duplicateCmdForPiping = strndup(pipeSeparatedCommand, strlen(pipeSeparatedCommand)); // duplicates command
        pipeSeparatedCommand = strtok(NULL, "|"); // starts at the NULL Character that was tokenized
        char *token = strtok(duplicateCmdForPiping, " "); // finds the first space in the command, tokenizes the arguments by this space
        int index = 0;  // counts the number of commands and arguments

        while (token != NULL) {
            if ((input != NULL) || (output != NULL)) { // advances to the next argument if input or output is found (does not include them in args)
                token = strtok(NULL, " "); 
                continue;
            }

            commandArgsCount[index]++;
            commandArray[numberOfPipes][index] = token; // sets the argument index equal to the address of token (containing the token)
            token = strtok(NULL, " "); // token will search for the next delimiter from the last delimiter end spot
            index++;    
        }

        commandArray[numberOfPipes + 1][index] = NULL; // prevents the args array from collecting garbage in memory.

        if (pipeSeparatedCommand != NULL) // catches the zero case
            numberOfPipes++; // this begins at zero, increments if more pipes need to be added

        free(duplicateCmdForPiping);
        duplicateCmdForPiping = NULL;
    }
```

Comment: You free them when you are certain they are no longer referenced anywhere else in the program, and they won't be necessary. When and where this criteria fits is up to you to decide as you write your code.

Comment: `commandArray[numberOfPipes][index] = token;` - that will be left with a *dangling pointer* once `free(duplicateCmdForPiping);` is called. This equally has as much to do with `malloc`/`free` as it does with how `strtok` works. (hint: it doesn't copy *anything*; rather it sets terminators in the original string (the result of your `strndup`) and returns pointers inside said-same).

Comment: @Frontear: That is not a correct criterion. It is fine to free memory for which there are still references, as long as those references will not be used. For example, when freeing several items on a linked list, we may free one item even though the previous item still points to it, because that previous item will also be freed momentarily or the pointer in it will be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the man page for `strtok()`. It says the function will return "a pointer to the beginning of each subsequent token in the string." I suggest you change the line

```
    commandArray[numberOfPipes][index] = token;
```

to

```
    // make sure you `#include <string.h>`
    strcpy(commandArray[numberOfPipes][index], token);
    // OR
    commandArray[numberOfPipes][index] = strdup(token);
```

By the way please avoid using camel-case variable naming convention in C/C++. It makes your code extremely hard to read.